# Simplistic word editor suggestions needed

Tags: software

I am looking for a minimalistic word editor for my creative writing. Basically I would like something like the “notes” app on OSX just with the option to save your writing as a separate file. Does anyone know of something like that?

Comment: [Writeapp](http://writeapp.net/notesexporter/)

Comment: @Alexander if you could expand on why that's a good suggestion it could make a great answer ;)

Comment: It would help to know what platform(s) you are using.

Comment: How minimalist we talking? Would Notepad.exe do?

Comment: If you're using a mac, try "TextEdit," it's built-in. You can also look into TextMate (on mac) or (if you're on Windows) Notepad++. They're both very simple text editors but they have support for markdown if you want to add some style.

Answer (score 1):

I like Notepad++.  It has more features than you might want, but it is NOT a document formatter.  It is nothing like Microsoft.  It is single font, which you can make be a fixed-space font for a typewriter look.  It loads quickly, saves files easily, keeps backup files, and doesn't take a lot to learn it.

But, it is multi-window, so you can edit more than one file at a time, or look up in one while writing in another.  It has some spell-checking ability you can add (or turn on), but it does not have (AFAIK) Grammerly integration.

If you want platform independence, Notepad++ works pretty well, with very similar products being available on Linux and Windows.

Have you considered using Google docs?